# Double integral of a single variable function (dependent random variables)

Tags: calculus, integration, conditional-probability

$$\int^a_0{\left(\int^b_0{f(y)\mathrm{d}y}\right)g(x)\mathrm{d}x}$$

In this relationship, $f(y)$ and $g(x)$ are probability distribution functions (PDF). If $x$ and $y$ are 'dependent' random variables, can we still say that:

$$\int^a_0{\left(\int^b_0{f(y)\mathrm{d}y}\right)g(x)\mathrm{d}x}=\left(\int^a_0{g(x)\mathrm{d}x}\right)\left(\int^b_0{f(y)\mathrm{d}y}\right)$$

Comment: What do you mean by $x$ and $y$ being "dependent random variables"?

Comment: As written, yep. Now if they’re not independent, the joint density will look a bit different.

Comment: That's right. It does however not jeopardize the good old calculus we can do with the two PDFs of their *marginal* distributions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. In other words: if $h(x,y)$ is the joint pdf then $f(y)=\int_0^b h(x,y)\,dx$ and $g(x)=\int_0^a h(x,y)\,dy\,.$ These two functions know nothing about dependency and your formulas above stay intact. Why should they not?

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone. In my problem, there is a random variable $N$ with a pdf of $f\left(N\right)$. Accordingly, the other two random variables $x$ and $y$ are defined based on $N$ so that $x=\alpha N$ and $y=\left(1-\alpha \right)N$, where $0<\alpha <1$. So, I consider $x$ and $y$ to be dependent. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hint: what is the covariance of $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: @KurtG Based the definition above, perhaps the covariance is -1.

Comment: There is no perhaps.
\begin{align}
E[xy]-E[x]E[y]&=(\alpha-\alpha^2)E[N^2]-\alpha E[N]\Big(E[N]-\alpha E[N]\Big)\\
&=(\alpha-\alpha^2)E[N^2]-(\alpha-\alpha^2)E[N]^2=(\alpha-\alpha^2){\rm Var}[N]\,.
\end{align}
This does not always look like $-1$ to me.

Comment: @KurtG. Wooow! This is amazing! Wrongly, it was almost obvious to me that it is -1. Thank you so much for correcting me! Is there any close form relationship so that using pdf of x, pdf of y, and the covariance (that you calculated), we obtain the joint pdf of x and y?

Comment: Not in general. The prime example of a joint pdf that can be parametrized by a covariance matrix is the $n$-dimensional normal pdf. Let's not get into an open ended discussion about such basic stuff. Keep working and ask detailed focused questions if necessary.

Comment: Even if for a continuous uniform pdf (e.g., $f (N )=\frac{1}{u}$ so that $N\in \left[0,u\right]$), there is a closed-form answer, it can help a lot. Even if there is any reference so that I follow the calculations, hopefully, I will try to extract the answer. Thanks again.